# jquery validationEngine not working

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to implement jquery validation engine in jsp but it is not working for me.
Please see code below:

```
<html lang="en"><head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
alert("hi");
jQuery("#empFrm").validationEngine();
});
</script>

<body>

<form:form method="post" action="" name="empForm" id="empFrm">

<input type="text"large" name="empId" class="validate[required] text-input" />
...
```

alert is coming but validation engine is not working.

Comment: Why are you loading 2 validationEngine files?

Comment: hi,                                                                    took reference from an example so forgot to delete jquery.validationEngine-en.js file.Deleted that file.Anyway that does not make any difference.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a few mistakes with your code. A couple tags not closed and fields without a ending quote in the proper place. In addition you shouldn't need to use "text-input" for a regular field. Take a look at what I have here and compare

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
                alert("hi"); 
                jQuery("#empFrm").validationEngine(); 
            }); 
        </script> 

    </head> 

    <body> 
        <form method="post" action="" name="empForm" id="empFrm"> 
            <input type="text" name="empId" class="validate[required]" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```